# Detect a non-gracefull disconnect in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a server/client application where the server sends data to the client and the client sends data back. But for some reason I can not manage to get it working since I dont know how to detect a non-graceful disconnect without writing data (I can not write data since the buffer will be filled with wrong data which I dont need). Is there another way to do it? I am using TCP.

Comment: TCP was designed to handle connection outages gracefully. The ability of TCP to recover from disappeared connections is a feature, not a bug. To put it another way: if no communication is going on, *there is no disconnect*. The traditional solution to this when you do need to know if the other side is still alive is to incorporate a periodic heartbeat into the protocol: some operation that does nothing except confirm that the other side is still there through the response. If there is no such operation, people occasionally use zero-byte writes, but this is not fully reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing the behavior of TCP connections on an unreliable network. So you need to use other protocol. Have a look at

[TCP C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is a reliable network BUT if the server disconnects I dont want to reconnect all my clients manually.

Comment: what protocol you are using?

Comment: @JesseVlietveld then you should be able to detect if TCP disconnect

Comment: Yes if it is done gracefully. But a non-gracefull disconnect is way harder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, but you could check if your socket is still connected:

```
public bool IsSocketConnected(Socket socket) {
    return !(socket.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0) && socket.Connected;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for a gracefull disconnect. But not for a non-gracefull disconnect. (when the server network disconnects randomly)

Comment: Deciding on a timeout (other than `0` as in the example) might be the pragmatic solution. If a disconnect happens ungracefully, then the "surviving" side will be trapped in the connected state until it either receives word to change state (which it can't because the that word would have to come from the side that is disconnected), or a timeout mechanism is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with a KeepAlive function.